# Cracking your head to find OR Cracking your head over?

Tags: expressions, prepositions

Which is the right way to say it? Got caught in a disagreement over this blog title.

Example usage:

> Cracking your head to find the perfect Christmas gifts?

Vs

> Cracking your head over the perfect Christmas gift?

Any references to grammer, language structures are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Both are a bit odd—too violent for Xmas—sounding more like a serious injury than anything else. It's not a phrase I've heard, anyhow. Phrases that come to mind include—"pulling your hair out", "driving you crazy", "doing your head in" (a bit milder than skull cracking), "driving you nuts", "driving you spare", "busting a gut", "wracking your brain" etc.

Comment: Yeah, neither one works for me.  "Banging your head" is at least more idiomatic.